# How do I expose data in a JSON format through a web service using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, json

Is there an easy way to return data to web service clients in JSON using Rails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails resource gives a RESTful interface for your model. Let's see.

## Model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

## Routes

```
map.resources :contacts
```

## Controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.xml {render :xml => @contact}
      format.js  {render :json => @contact.json}
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

So this gives you an API interfaces without the need to define special methods to get the type of respond required

Eg.

```
/contacts/1 # Responds with regular html page

/contacts/1.xml # Responds with xml output of Contact.find(1) and its attributes

/contacts/1.js # Responds with json output of Contact.find(1) and its attributes
```

Comment: Great answer! If I may update it to Rails 3, the json method now seems to be to_json. At least that's what worked for me... i.e. @contact.to_json

Answer (score 4):

http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoGenerateJSON

Answer (score 2):

Rails monkeypatches most things you'd care about to have a `#to_json` method.

Off the top of my head, you can do it for hashes, arrays, and ActiveRecord objects, which should cover about 95% of the use cases you might want. If you have your own custom objects, it's trivial to write your own `to_json` method for them, which can just jam data into a hash and then return the jsonized hash.

Comment: monkeypatches?  I have no idea what that means, but I could guess it refers to providing that method to most, if not all, objects

Comment: It's patching an existing object, adding the method or changing it if it exists.  It's really just dynamic language extension.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that does just this,
http://blog.labnotes.org/2007/12/11/json_request-handling-json-request-in-rails-20/

And from what I understand this functionality is already in Rails. But go see that blog post, there are code examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord also provides methods to interact with JSON. To create JSON out of an AR object, just call object.to_json. TO create an AR object out of JSON you should be able to create a new AR object and then call object.from_json.. as far as I understood, but this did not work for me.